# adding list to array of list in localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, local-storage

I have list of students like as follows form from user input form:

```
 //student form input for 1st time
 var student={name:"a",roll:"9",age:13}
 //student form input for 2nd time
 var student={name:"b",roll:"10",age:14}
 //student form input for 3rd time
 var student={name:"c",roll:"11",age:15}
```

Actually, i am developing phonegap applications. Each time the user submit form-input i.e. student information, I want to save them into localstorage. Finally, when online, i want to sync them. I know i can store them in localstorage as follows:

```
 localStorage.setItem("studentinfo", JSON.Stringfy(student));
```

But, this will remove the first student info in the local storage when i save second student info.

Infact, when i save first, second and third input respectively, i want to add them in localstorage array and finally the result in localstorage should be like

```
key=studentlist,
value=[
       {name:"a",roll:"9",age:13},  
       {name:"b",roll:"10",age:14},
       {name:"c",roll:"11",age:15}
    ]
```

How can it be done in localstorage or phonegap localstorage?

Comment: You should stringfy the json object containing all students, not just stringfy student one by one. In second case, you are overriding you localstorage key "studentinfo". Localstorage works only with string (key:value). You could create a new key for each student too, but you have to code corresponding logic then by setting an unique key for each student

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want to hold all your students in an array like this:

```
var students = [];
students.push({name:"a",roll:"9",age:13});
students.push({name:"b",roll:"10",age:14});
students.push({name:"c",roll:"11",age:15});
```

And then store that in `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.setItem('studentsInfo', JSON.stringify(students));
```

The best way to do that would be with a function like this:

```
// When you get more student information, you should:
var addNewStudent = function (name, roll, age) {
    // retrieve it (Or create a blank array if there isn't any info saved yet),
    var students = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('studentsInfo')) || [];
    // add to it,
    students.push({name: name, roll: roll, age: age});
    // then put it back.
    localStorage.setItem('studentsInfo', JSON.stringify(students));
}
```